# PDF 1.7 - How exactly does the CTM (Current Transformation Matrix) work?

Tags: pdf, matrix

After reading the [Adobe PDF 1.7 (ISO 32000-1:2008) specification](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf), I'm still having trouble understanding how to properly create my transformation matrix.

The specification in section 4.2/4.3 state the following:

> • Translations are specified as [ 1 0 0 1 tx ty ], where tx and ty
>   are the distances  to translate the origin of the coordinate system in
>   the horizontal and vertical  dimensions, respectively.
>   •
>   Scaling is obtained by [ sx 0 0 sy 0 0 ]. This scales the coordinates
>   so that 1  unit in the horizontal and vertical dimensions of the new
>   coordinate system is  the same size as sx and sy units, respectively,
>   in the previous coordinate system.
>  • Rotations are produced by [
>   cos θ sin θ −sin θ cos θ 0 0 ], which has the effect  of rotating the
>   coordinate system axes by an angle θ counterclockwise.
>  • Skew is
>   specified by [ 1 tan α tan β 1 0 0 ], which skews the x axis by an
>   angle  α and the y axis by an angle β.

Given this, how exactly does one go about using transformations in sequence with each other?

I can successfully use the `Translation` and `Rotation` together, but when I attempt to also use `Scaling` or `Skewing` things go severely wrong. Perhaps I'm using the CTM incorrectly or maybe even my math is off. I am attempting to create text at coordinate position (50, 50) with a rotation of 45 degrees and a scaling of 2 (in that order). The reason why I state "*In that order*" is because the specification states that ordering of transformations makes a difference (the spec gives a graphical example of the differences based on the transformation ordering). So what would the stream object look like and/or how would the matrix mathematics apply here?

Working (Transformation of (50, 50) + 45 degree rotation)

```
[ 1  0  0 ]   [  0.707 0.707 0 ]   [  0.707  0.707 0 ]
[ 0  1  0 ] x [ -0.707 0.707 0 ] = [ -0.707  0.707 0 ]
[ 50 50 1 ]   [  0     0     1 ]   [ 50.000 50.000 1 ]

BT
  0.707 0.707 -0.707 0.707 50 50 Tm
  /F1 36 Tf
  (Hello, World!) Tj
ET
```

When I try to do matrix multiplication to add scaling, it doesn't seem to work:

```
[  0.707  0.707 0 ]   [ 2 0 0 ]   [   1.414   1.414 0 ]
[ -0.707  0.707 0 ] x [ 0 2 0 ] = [  -1.414   1.414 0 ]
[ 50.000 50.000 1 ]   [ 0 0 1 ]   [ 100.000 100.000 1 ]
```

The math seems correct, except now the text starts at coordinate (100, 100) instead of (50, 50). This just doesn't seem correct to me, since I'm trying to start at (50, 50), rotate by 45 degrees, then scale it by 2.

Comment: BTW, you executed the first matrix multiplication the other way around, rotation x translation gives your result, not translation x rotation as you wrote.

Comment: Ah you are correct sir.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> The math seems correct, except now the text starts at coordinate (100, 100) instead of (50, 50). This just doesn't seem correct to me, since I'm trying to start at (50, 50), rotate by 45 degrees, then scale it by 2.

But that **does** make sense. If you first translate by (50, 50) and then scale by two, you effectively translate by (50, 50) times two, i.e. (100, 100).

What you seem to need is to first scale by two (to have thing twice the size, but not yet moved or rotated) and only thereafter rotate and translate (without scaling affecting the translation), i.e.

```
[ 2 0 0 ]   [  0.707  0.707 0 ]   [   1.414   1.414 0 ]
[ 0 2 0 ] x [ -0.707  0.707 0 ] = [  -1.414   1.414 0 ]
[ 0 0 1 ]   [ 50.000 50.000 1 ]   [  50.000  50.000 1 ]
```

Some hand-waving: What you had in mind when you said

> I am attempting to create text at coordinate position (50, 50) with a rotation of 45 degrees and a scaling of 2 (in that order).

surely was that after translating to (50, 50), the following operations should leave the point (50, 50) fixed. But that's not what the other operations do, they keep the origin (0,0) fixed. Thus you should first scale and rotate your object at the origin and only thereafter translate it, at least to match what you had in mind...

Comment: So I was implementing the transforms correctly in code, but I just didn't convey what I wanted in my head correctly (i.e. Text twice the normal size at a 45 degree angle at point (50, 50))?

Comment: Also, does the PDF 1.7 (ISO 32000-1:2008) standard have a way to automatically do the matrix multiplication for me, or do I have to code that up?

Comment: You don't need to multiply the matrices yourself. If you use operations for ctm manipulation, not text matrix manipulation, they are combined: the new one is multiplied with the existing ctm from the left side.

Comment: So, I would do something like `2 0 0 2 0 0 cm 0.707 0.707 -0.707 0.707 0 0 cm 1 0 0 1 50 50 Tm`?

Comment: The other way around. The first operation in the stream is operated last. And don't forget using q and Q to reset the transformation as far as you may need to, just as yms mentioned in his answer.

Comment: Interesting, so I have to do it one direction when I am doing matrix multiplication, and the opposite direction when using the `cm` operator.

Comment: Yes. `A cm B cm C cm` is the same as `(C x B x A) cm`.

Comment: I guess it is easier to think of it as 'M cm' being the same as 'CURRENT_MATRIX = M x CURRENT_MATRIX'

Comment: If someone wants to understand the use of the transformation matrix this Article is the best resource I have used. It explains the matrix multiplication part and all transformation operations with easy to understand examples https://forum.patagames.com/posts/t501-What-Is-Transformation-Matrix-and-How-to-Use-It

Answer (score 3):

The operator Tm is used for *setting* the text matrix, which is combined with the Current Transformation Matrix when the text is rendered.

Instead you could use the cm operator (concatenate matrix), which is going to do all the math operations for you. If you want to keep the original matrix that was used before you started outputting the text, you could use the operators q/Q to save/restore the current graphic state.